# Android export as .dwg

Tags: android, autocad, cad, dxf, dwg

I'm new in Android and CAD. I need to do an app in which user can draw objects and after export as .dwg format to open in AutoCAD and make some changes. How I can export it as .dwg? Is there any java libraries? I found library YCad to deal with .dxf format. Can you please explain me disadvantage of .dxf? I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AutoCAD 360 (run on browser or mobile) and save on Autodesk cloud, then use Webdav to get the file. See https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autodesk.autocadws

Or use AutoCAD I/O, which is a webservice, to generate .dwg files from any device (via REST calls). This is a data only webservice, so no wysiwyg editing. See http://developer.autodesk.com

Comment: Can I export drawing as .pdf and then convert it to .dwg? Is that possible? What about quality lose. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Converto from PDF to DWG is possible with some tools, but the quality really depends on the PDF quality... quick google search show a few results.

Answer (score 1):

Teigha from Open Design Alliance can read and write dwg files. It also has Teigha.Java wrapper and can be used from Java applications. Take a look at http://opendesign.com/

The main disadvantage of dxf is that not all AutoCAD entities can be saved to dxf, dxf covers only a part of what can be saved to dwg.